# Stop autocycle of image slider when activity destroyed / finish()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager, activity-lifecycle, androidimageslider

I am using an Image slider by https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider

Which is a image slider showing in login activity, 
When activity A(login) start activity B(Dashboard) by finish() intent, In Android Studio Monitor I can still see the slider is rotating where activity A(login) is onStop() state

I am already calling

```
@Override
protected void onStop() { 
   mDemoSlider.stopAutoCycle();
    super.onStop();
}
```

In activity A but still when Activity B start Android Studio Monitor Showing continuous changes of pages by:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    Log.d("Slider Demo", "Page Changed: " + position);
}
```

### D/Slider Demo: Page Changed: 0 D/Slider Demo: Page Changed: 1 D/Slider Demo: Page Changed: 2 D/Slider Demo: Page Changed: 3 D/Slider Demo: Page Changed: 4 D/Slider Demo: Page Changed: 0 D/Slider Demo: Page Changed: 1 D/Slider Demo: Page Changed: 2

Comment: Try calling `mDemoSlider.stopAutoCycle();` in `onPause`

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply still not work , I am also setting FLAG addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); before starting the activity , but when activity B start in background pager is rotating continuously

Answer (score 0):

When starting Activity B at that place put this before starting Activity

put : `sliderView.stopAutoCycle();`

and put this on in  Activity A

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    sliderView.startAutoCycle();

}
```